# How to install several independent firefox instances on ubuntu?

Tags: firefox

My wife helps out a friend with managing the social media accounts of their small business. For that, she would like to have three independent Firefox instances installed on her Ubuntu laptop, because she frequently uses different logins for facebook, twitter, etc. at the same time. Additionally, she wants that

- Firefox remembers the logins, but separately for each instance, so she can always be logged in e.g. facebook with three different accounts. Logins and passwords should not be shared between the instances.
- Each firefox instance is somehow distinguishable by a different theme color or something.
- all of the instances share her Home folder, where she keeps all her files
- Any changes to her workflow are not debatable :-)

**What I tried:**

First, I wanted to just create three different users and run one version of firefox as each. Then I though about the home drive problem, and resorted to Docker. I created three docker containers running firefox, used an extension to color the tabs and mounted the home folder. Unfortunately, firefox seems to run very unstable in a docker container, tabs frequently are crashing, and there are additional problems (e.g. sound) that are for sure solvable, but I am asking if anyone knows another way to achieve her goal?

Apparently, firefox creates some hidden folders in the HOME directory, where stuff like extensions and logins are stored. Is there a way to change that location? Any other ideas? I was reading about "Profiles" in firefox, but was not able to find that in the newer versions (she uses v57 I think).